# Not able to use echo in my unix script

Tags: bash, unix

when i define echo in my unix script, my script is not working. Where as if i execute it individually it is working fine. Please help me here. Echo in my script looks as below.

```
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('`date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m'`)" >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

here $1 is i want to pass a value when executing script. That is working fine with script execution.

The script error is below.

> echo 'Subject :PCDM smart Monthly  Recon Report('
>   techo.ksh: line 3: syntax error at line 3: `)' unexpected

Comment: Why does the file name in the error message looks like a korn shell script, whilst this question is tagged with `bash`?

Comment: I'm concerned that you state that when you execute it individually it is working fine, and that the error comes from line 3, even though you only show one line.  The problem is that it could be the *previous* line (line 2) causing the error with, for example, a missing quote.  Line numbers only show where the error was *detected*, not where it is.  Please show the previous lines in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect quoting:

```
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('`date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m'`)" >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

Should be:

```
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('`date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m`')" >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

You mixed-up the trailing back-tick and single quote, which was hard to see.  This is a really good reason for not using the DEPRECATED back-tick syntax, as @Oleg Vaskevich stated.  So:

```
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('$(date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m)')" >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should in general try to use `$(your command)` instead of `your command`. This works for me, though:

```
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('$(date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m)')" >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

However, your code might be easier to read if you write it like this:

```
date=$(date --date="1 months ago" +%Y%m)
echo "Subject :PCDM $1 Monthly  Recon Report('$date')" \
    >> pcdm_monthly_recon_mailheader1
```

Comment: Although this is all correct, I don't see how it answers the question.  Shouldn't this have gone into a comment?

Comment: The question wasn't clearly worded at the beginning and there were formatting errors, so I thought OP simply had too many quotes or something.

Comment: I agree, and on closer inspection you fixed it by suggesting the `$( )` syntax.